# Finite field roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $p,q \equiv 1 \pmod{4} $ are primes. Let $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be a field of $q$ elements and let $\mathbb{F}_Q$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. Let $K$ be the set of roots of $x^p-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$. 
I need to show that there exists an element $r\in K$ such that the set of roots of $x^{p}-1$ is $\{1,r,r^2,...,r^{p-1}\}$.
 I was thinking that if $x^p-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$, then all of the roots of $x^p-1$ form a basis for a $p$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{Q}$, but I am not sure how to proceed.
I also need to show that setting $T = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} r^{k^{2}}$ implies $T^2 = p$.

Comment: That is weird notation: The letter $K$ suggests that it be a field, but it’s not as zero is no root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

For $q \nmid n$, let $\Bbb{F}_{q^f}$ be $x^n-1\in \Bbb{F}_q[x]$'s splitting field.

For each $d | n$,
$x^d-1$ has exactly $d$ roots in the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^f}$

(proof : it has at most $d$ roots, and if it has less than $d$ roots it must have a double root $a$ which must be a root of $(x^d-1)'=d x^{d-1}$ ie. $a=0$, contradiction)

$$n = \prod_{j=1}^J p^{e_j}$$

For each $j$ this implies there is a root $b_j$ of $x^{p_j^{e_j}}-1$ which is not a root of $x^{p_j^{e_j-1}}-1$,

thus $b_j$ is of order $p_j^{e_j}$ in $\Bbb{F}_{q^f}^\times$ so that $$c = \prod_{j=1}^J b_j$$ is of order $n$ in $\Bbb{F}_{q^f}^\times$.

Whence $c$ generates a cyclic group with $n$ elements and they must be all the roots of $x^n-1$.

The case $q | n$ follows from $x^n-1=  (x^{n/q}-1)^q$.